# Selenium - expanding an element doesn't work, while collapsing does

Tags: java, selenium

I'm writing a test to expand and collapse certain collapsible elements on a page. URL: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/panels-wells.html

I've got this code in my page object:

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@id,'accordion')]")
List<WebElement> collapsibleItems;

@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(@id,'collapse')]")
List<WebElement> collapsibleTexts;

public boolean checkIfElementIsExpanded(String value) {
    for (WebElement collapsibleText:collapsibleTexts) {
        return collapsibleText.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='collapse" + value + "\']/div")).isDisplayed();
    }
    return false;
}

public void collapseAnItem(String value, int number) {
    for (WebElement collapsibleItem : collapsibleItems) {
        if(checkIfElementIsExpanded(value)==true) {
            collapsibleItem.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='accordion']/div[" + number + "]/div[1]/h4/a"))).click();
        }       
    }
}

public void expandAnItem(String value, int number) {
    for (WebElement collapsibleItem : collapsibleItems) {
        if(checkIfElementIsExpanded(value)==false) {
            collapsibleItem.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='accordion']/div[" + number + "]/div[1]/h4/a"))).click();
        }       
    }
}
```

When I want to collapse an element, everything works fine. However, when I try to expand an element, it doesn't do anything - there's no exception but the code isn't executed. What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

Comment: There is not enough info here to help you find the reason. Can you post the link to your page? Or at least some screenshots/html?

Comment: Also
1) You dont need to have == true in  if(checkIfElementIsExpanded(value)==true)
   just if(checkIfElementIsExpanded(value)) will do the job
2) for the if(checkIfElementIsExpanded(value)==false)
  replace it with if(!checkIfElementIsExpanded(value))
! at the front will check opposite

Comment: I've actually tried using  if(!checkIfElementIsExpanded(value)) but it didn't work as well. Here's a screenshot of the elements: https://imgur.com/nuDTcEc. I'm collapsing #1 and trying to expand #3. Here's the html: https://imgur.com/0DgiLLD. I hope that will suffice

Comment: Can you provide url to your page?

Comment: What is String value when you trying to expand?

Comment: https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/panels-wells.html

Comment: I'm typing this: panelsAndWellsPage.expandAnItem("Three",3);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though there are lots of improvements that can be done to your code, it's still working if you add some waits. You have this expand and collapse animations, so you need to add some waits for elements to become visible or invisible after expand and collapse. 
I recreated your code and ran it in chrome with waits, and I was able to collapse first and expand third item with no changes.

Also, here are few suggestions to improve your code.
1 - Dont use PageFactory, it doesn't provide any benefits. Save your locators in By elements, if you want your code to look cleaner.

2 - You dont need those loops. Since you specify what element number you want to use, you can get it directly. Without loops.

3 - You dont need ==true or ==false inside of if statements

4 - String value and int number basically do the same job, so you can drop one of them.

Below is improved code, that does what you need:

```
    public boolean checkIfElementIsExpanded(int number) {
        WebElement textElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='accordion']/div[" + number + "]/div[2]")));
        return textElement.isDisplayed();
    }


    public void collapseAnItem(int number) {
        WebElement itemHeader = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='accordion']/div[" + number + "]/div[1]/h4/a")));
        if (checkIfElementIsExpanded(number)) {
            itemHeader.click();
        }

        // Since you collapsing item, text will become invisible, so we need to wait for invisibility
        WebElement textElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='accordion']/div[" + number + "]/div[2]")));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(textElement));
    }


    public void expandAnItem(int number) {
        WebElement itemHeader = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='accordion']/div[" + number + "]/div[1]/h4/a")));
        if (!checkIfElementIsExpanded(number)) {
            itemHeader.click();
        }

        // Since you collapsing item, text will become visible, so we need to wait for visibility
        WebElement textElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//*[@id='accordion']/div[" + number + "]/div[2]")));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(textElement));
    }
```

For your test, I added prints, so you can see results:

```
System.out.println("Is element number 1 expanded: " + panelsAndWellsPage.checkIfElementIsExpanded(1));
panelsAndWellsPage.collapseAnItem(1);
System.out.println("Is element number 1 expanded: " + panelsAndWellsPage.checkIfElementIsExpanded(1));

System.out.println("Is element number 3 expanded: " + panelsAndWellsPage.checkIfElementIsExpanded(3));
panelsAndWellsPage.expandAnItem(3);
System.out.println("Is element number 3 expanded: " + panelsAndWellsPage.checkIfElementIsExpanded(3));
```